# How does free() interact with a struct made on the stack that contains an array made on the heap?

Tags: c, struct, heap-memory

Say I want to create a new struct that contains image data

```
struct Image {
    int *pxl_arr;
    int pxl_arr_len;
    int img_wdt, img_hgt;
};
```

And I also had a separate function that opened an image file and copied the contents of the  file into an array of integers made on the heap using malloc(), so that some other function could parse that data and use it with the `struct Image`

```
int *freadarr (char *fpath) {
    FILE *fptr;
    long len;
    int *buf;

 /* code to open file here */

    buf = (int *) malloc(len);

 /* code to read from file here */ 

    return buf;
}
```

Then inside of the `main()` function, I were to do this:

```
int main() {
    struct Image img;
    img.pxl_arr = freadarr(/* whatever the file path is */);
    free(img);
    return 0;
}
```

What would `free()` do with the `struct Image`?

EDIT: `img.pxl_arr`, not `img->pxl_arr`

Comment: you should not free things that are not allocated on the heap

Answer (score 2):

> What would free() do with the struct Image?

Nothing, as you should only pass to `free` any pointer value returned from `malloc` (or `calloc` / `realloc`), or `NULL`. In your (slightly flawed) example, that would be the value held by the `pxl_arr` member of the structure.

Or maybe *anything*, as passing any other value is [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior), but your compiler should complain loudly about `free(img);`:

```
main.c:12:10: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘free’
   12 |     free(img);
      |          ^~~
      |          |
      |          struct Image
```

Pass the pointer value to `free` when you are done with it:

```
struct Image img;
img.pxl_arr = freadarr(/* whatever the file path is */);
/* ... do stuff .. */
free(img.pxl_arr);
```

Note that `->` is for accessing the members of a structure via a pointer. `img` is not a pointer, so use the `.` operator. See: [Member access operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_member_access)

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. Also thanks for catching the `.` vs `->` typo, I tend to get those confused a lot.

Comment: @TheBlizWiz, the `->` operator is an arrow, *pointing* at the member name.  It is the one used with structure *pointers*.

Answer (score 0):

`free(struct)` is use to free (hehe) the memory that have been recerved to `struct`.

In this case you will lose the info inside `struct Image`, that means one Pointer and 2 Integers, if and only if the `struct Image` have been recerved with `malloc()`.